# Google Web Font - Poor Rendering in IE9 & 10

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, google-webfonts

I am working on a new build and am @importing a Google Webfont, Rokkitt.  I need to use this in both the standard and bold versions for my site.  When I include this font and test, the fonts look clean and as expected with the only exceptions being IE 9 & 10.  In these two versions the text is rendered without any aliasing and smoothing.

My search on this topic has really only shown results pertaining to Chrome so I am not too sure where to look or what to try at this point.

I have tried the standard text-shadow trick with no luck, as well as other less-likely solutions such as the CSS smoothing technique.  I have yet to find anything that makes the font suitable in these two browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use CSS3 @font-face rule to achieve your goal.

Note that Internet Explorer 9 and Internet Explorer 10 dose not support for TTF (True Type Fonts). Internet explorer 9 & 10 supports WOFF(Web Open Font Format) fonts and EOT (Embedded OpenType) fonts.

**Note:** Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the @font-face rule.

**Reference:** 
[CSS3 fonts - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_fonts.asp)